# Deploy C# - SQL Server project

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, deployment

I want to deploy a project which is coded in C# with SQL Server as the database server.

I have to deploy the project where there is no SQL Server installed.

Anybody have any idea about how this can be done?

Thanks.

Comment: Why create a database schema if there is no database is installed? Or do you need to install the database server, and want to know how to deploy the schema from development to production? Or are you looking for suggestions for a embedded database server?

Answer (score 1):

A full SQL Server install is probably not something you should even try to deploy - licensing aside, the configuration of a SQL server is environment dependent. It would be better to list sql server as a pre-requisite *in documentation only*, and get it installed manually.

If your database is smaller, though, a [SQL server **express**](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/) install might be reasonable to embed in an installer (if you use a named instance); IIRC the larger version of the installer allows you to create a custom installer for an application, ideal for deployment scenarios.

Even better; if you can fit into [SQL server **compact**](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/compact.aspx), then that is an embedded server; there is no install as such - just ship the runtime with the application.

Comment: Thanks @Marc

I got that it will good to use **SQL Server Compact** 

Well i Need procedure to deploy my project with database

Will you please tell  me step involving in same